# TypeScript no warning for (array | undefined).forEach

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm running into a problem that TypeScript should solve for me, but it doesn't. I have a value which is sometimes an `array` and sometimes `null`/`undefined`. I want to call `forEach` on this value, but I need to make sure that every time I call it, I'm using optional chaining to prevent errors. But TypeScript isn't warning me when I leave out the optional chaining. I've tried many different ways of declaring this type, none of which have worked. I have a 10,000 line file that I'm trying to make run smoothly, and don't want to have to keep hand-combing through to catch these problems.

`maybeArray.forEach(...)` -> `maybeArray?.forEach(...)`

Is there any way to get TypeScript to warn me when I leave off the optional chaining?

I'm using TypeScript 5.3.3 with Node.js in Visual Studio Code.

[image]

Here's the simplest version:

```
const maybeArray: number[] | undefined = undefined;
maybeArray.forEach(val=>val++); // no TypeScript warning, but there should be.
// note that on the above line, mousing over maybeArray shows "const maybeArray: number[]".
```

I've also tried

```
type MaybeArray = number[] | undefined;

const maybeArray: MaybeArray = undefined;
maybeArray.forEach(val=>val++); // no TypeScript warning, but there should be.
```

And I've also tried

```
type MaybeArray = number[] | undefined;

const maybeArray = undefined;
(maybeArray as MaybeArray).forEach(val=>val++); // no TypeScript warning, but there should be.
```

And even

```
type MyObject = {
  maybeArray?: number[],
};

const myObject:MyObject = {};
(myObject.maybeArray).forEach(val=>val++); // no TypeScript warning, but there should be.
```

I thought I could get a useful result by using `false` instead of `undefined`, but `false` doesn't work with optional chaining.

```
type MaybeArray = number[] | false;

const maybeArray = false;
(maybeArray as MaybeArray)?.forEach(val=>val++); // correct TypeScript warning because optional chaining doesn't work on FALSE.
```

tscongif:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types","./node_modules/@types"],
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strict": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Pasting your simplest example into the ts playground gave and error. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwJ4CMCmBBATl5AuGMAVznSwG0BdGAHxiLABM0AzASzDUZgF56nWHLgG4AUIlSYcyAHQsQWAKIJgACwAUANwQAbHgD5tOgNTGAlMJgB6K4RAwAKkgAOaAMrAsbZ7ADuCLDAOAHMAGhgUIlgoVTQsNBgIVRAiHW50GVEbOygEmIRYcBgYhIQUEE0EnSFwuBSIEJgKuPhkdGxcJETk3wgYACJQSFgJdukkAmJSOKp+zKA)

Comment: maybe share your ts config?

Comment: Changing the tsconfig settings worked, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the following value in my `tscongif.json` file, which fixed the problem (caused TypeScript to show the correct warnings):

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "strictNullChecks": true
}
```